# how can I bulk load data for a family provider in riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm using Riverpod in my flutter application, which can display a list of items, and update them.

I've got a FutureProvider for searching items, which returns a list of items

I also have a FutureProvider family which I use to get individual items, which relies on a server call to get each individual item

And finally, I can update items from the UI, in which case I call the server to update the item, and then I invalidate() the relevant provider to trigger a refresh

The above setup implies a lot of server calls:

- I'm getting a list of items (first call)
- although I've got everything needed in this list of items, my widgets are linked to the family provider, so I'm calling the server once per item which in turns calls the sever once per item
- and finally, when I'm updating an item, instead of doing it locally (optimistic update) as well as on the server, I do it on the server and then call the server yet another time to retrieve the updated item

---

I'm looking for the best way to avoid all those server calls.

I was considering maintaining a local cache in which I could :

- bulk load the data when I get of list of items
- update an item directly when it's modified from the UI.

In that case the FutureProvider family would first check the cache before calling the server.

This means I would have to handle myself all the logic to remove items from the cache when needed (eg too old, or not watched anymore), and I feel a little bit like reinventing the wheel here, since Riverpod already has autodispose and keepalive ...

Is there a recommended way to handle this use case ? Am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: It kind of depends on the constraints of your server and how your client is designed. For example maybe instead of fetching items by ID, you could use a paginated API.

Comment: @RémiRousselet I actually have a paginated API for the search feature but I don't see how this helps. My problem (as I understand it ...) is that I want to mix single item providers (my family providers) with methods that return bulk data from the server. I don't know how to do that without rewriting some caching logic, and it seems to me to be a quite common use case, so I was thinking Riverpod might have something built-in for that !

Comment: @RémiRousselet For example, ReactQueries has "initialData" to address this exact scenario (see https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/initial-query-data)

Comment: Why not return your "initalData" directly in the initialization method of a provider?

Comment: @RémiRousselet This is exactly what I was planning on doing. It means I need to maintain a cache, along with timestamps to invalidate old data (the equivalent of reactqueries staleTime). Nothing difficult in itself, but I thought maybe something like that already existed in a framework described as a "caching" framework...

Comment: I don't understand your point. You said RQ's "initial query data" solves this, and you could do that in the provider function. So I don't get what the issue is

Comment: Maybe you want a `ref.exists(provider)`. Some people requested one before but I rejected it because it's unsafe. But it's probably reasonable to have one anyway and discourage it unless you know what you're doing. https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/1843

Comment: @RémiRousselet In ReactQueries I can write from anywhere "this is the new value for this query, and it expires in 5 minutes, at which point please reload it if it is requested again". This is one line of code. In Riverpod, if I understand correctly, it's my responsibility to create a cache provider, update it when needed, and to determine based on this cache if I need to make a network call. It seems to me to be a common use case, which a full-fledged caching library might have an interest in addressing, so I wanted to double check I wasn't missing anything ...

Comment: No you should be able to do exactly what you've described. But that's not what your question is asking for.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Yep I agree my question was poorly worded. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In any case, I've added request deduplication to the documentation plan